# iOS 7 Background task with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, download, background-transfer

i am downloading image in background with background session. and I have some queries related it .

1) will it work if i removed my app from background? I think it will work only in suspended state.

2) why we need self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler in handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession method.

3)Why we need to implement URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession?

Answer (score 4):

1. If you have already started a download task before the app terminates then your app will be launched in the background to give
   you a download finished callback.
2. we need self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler to call the completion handler once all the download tasks in a session are
   finished. If you don't call the completion handler, your app will be
   killed in the background saying assertions beyond permitted time.
3. we need URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession to handle scenario mentioned in point 1 above and to call the
   completionhandler of that session once all the download tasks in
   that session are completed.